# polar coordinates of a vector in three-dimensional space

Tags: math, 3d

polar coordinates of a 2 dimensional vector are:

```
x = r cos θ
y = r sin θ
```

What will be the polar coordinates of a vector in 3D  `(x, y, z)`?

Comment: **Equations for what?** Are you looking for the parameterization of a sphere in 3D (corresponding to a circle in 2D)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the responders to this question and the authors of the literature on the internet really understand what 3D polar coordinates are.  The only concise definition I have found thus far has been in the Schaum's Outline Series "Analytic Geometry" on page 145.

For 2D polar coordinates, a radius and one angle are all that is needed to define a point on a plane in polar coordinates.  But, for 3D polar, a radius and 3 angles are needed.  The first angle is from the x-axis to the radius, the second angle from the y-axis to the radius, and the third angle from the z-axis to the radius.  Notice that I said from the coordinate axis to the radius, not the coordinate axis to the projection of the radius on the xy-plane.

All of the discussions I have seen thus far devolve into cylindrical or spherical coordinate systems which measure from the x-axis to the projection of the radius to the xy-plane and don't use the angle from the y-axis to the radius at all.

An example exercise from the Schaum's book cited above is as follows.

Given point is {1,-2,2}

Answer: 3D Polar coordinate are {3,70°32',131°49',48°11'}

Unfortunately, Mathematica is completely AWOL on 3D polar as far as know.

Answer (score 21):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvilinear_coordinates#Example:_Spherical_coordinates):

> x = r sin θ cos φ
>   y = r sin θ sin φ
>   z = r cos θ

Comment: I can't believe this was downvoted. Here is a +1 to compensate for it.

Comment: @EOL Maybe because it doesn't give any explanations (at least a single word) of what those equations mean or what he's talking about. It just presents a bunch of equations and says, that's what you need, look at Wikipedia to understand what it means. But Ok, in this regard it's at least in sync with the senseless question. I'm not the downvoter though, this is probably what the OP meant.

Comment: For anyone wondering, **φ** is Camera Pan and **θ** is Camera Tilt

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what coordinate system you want in 3D. The above 2D transformation can be extended to both spherical and [cylindrical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system) via two clear geometrical analogues. For the case of cylindrical coordinates you would keep the above transformation for both x and y, but for z, the transformation would be given simply by z = z. So the transformation would be

```
(x, y, z) -> (r, theta, z)
```

For [spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) there is an introduction of an additional coordinate transformation in the z-direction (see Ignacio Vazque-Abrams answer above) and also changes to the x and y transforms. In this case you have

```
(x, y, z) -> (r, theta, phi)
```

I think in your case you would be best using cylindrical coordinates. I hope this helps.

Comment: As he doesn't present any case or what he really wants, I guess, that your last sentence/paragraph is also just a wild guess. But still the best answer, +1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the spherical coordinate system:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system

The link shows the conversions to x,y,z.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use the Mathematica function CoordinateTransform to conert a 3D cartesian point into a polar point, a message will appear saying it can't be done.

If you try to use the Mathematica function ToPolarCoordinates, an incorrect answer will appear with no indication that the result is wrong.

I can't figure out why there is so little literature on 3D polar coordinates or why Mathematica has not supported it correctly by now.

By the way, 3D polar coordinates are not the same as spherical or cylindrical coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I also think answer posted above by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams is correct.

x = r sin θ cos φ 
y = r sin θ sin φ 
z = r cos θ

If we think of an arbitary vetctor A with with magnitude r, which is making theta degree angle with z axis.
Then its projection along z axis will be r cos θ, while r sin θ will give A vectors projection on xy- plane.
Now if on xy plane, a 2d vector to the projected point (r sin θ) from above is making angle  phi with x axis, then (r sin θ)'s its cos φ will give x axis projection and sin φ will give y projection just like in 2d plane. i.e.
x = r sin θ cos φ 
y = r sin θ sin φ